# Separating values of items retrieved from the database in a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following procedure that serves to show in a DropDownList the "Descricao" values ​​in my database:

```
public void descricaoEntrada()
    {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.Append("SELECT [Descricao], [IDEntrada] FROM [dbo].[Entrada] where IDEntradaTipo = 2 order by Descricao");
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringSQL"].ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = Utils.DatabaseManagement.ExecuteReader(sql.ToString(), connection);
            descricao.DataSource = dr;
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                descricao.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["Descricao"].ToString(), dr["IDEntrada"].ToString()));
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

My query also retrieves another field called "IDEntrada" and I retrieve it in:

```
descricao.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["Descricao"].ToString(), dr["IDEntrada"].ToString()));
```

Then over my code I'm trying to retrieve the value of the "Descricao" and the value of the "IDEntrada" through the command:

```
descricao.Text
```

But the only thing that is retrieved is the value of "IDEntrada", and I want to be able to separately recover both the "IDEntrada" and the value "Descricao"

I want to retrieve values ​​separately in variables.

How can I do this?

Comment: Side note: Your `catch` block serves no purpose, and is actually removing useful information from the exception.  It should be removed entirely.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need following line.

```
descricao.DataSource = dr; //remove this line
```

You are setting `Descricao` as your dropdown option's text and `IDEntrada` as its value.

So in your case, to get selected item's text (i.e. `Descricao`) use:

```
descricao.SelectedItem.Text
```

And To get selected item's value (i.e. `IDEntrada`) use:

```
descricao.SelectedItem.Value
```

or

```
descricao.SelectedValue
```